# How to create Android themes

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 4.1-jelly-bean, launcher, customization, themes

I would like to create a whole new theme for Android jelly bean but not sure where to start. I have rooted my phone and have poked around the file system a little but haven't really seen all that much that would help.

I would like to completely change the LockScreen, Homescreen(s) the menu layout, icons, wallpaper, etc. It's not going to be just a launcher theme but a whole UI theme. I have spent a while searching for a solution (links, articles, any resources) but have not found anything that would be of much help.

If you know how to do this, or know of any resources at all that would help I'd be extremely grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Since this is more of a development question in which [android.se] consider out of scope, this question is more likely to be migrated to our sister site [so]. You would get better answers there. After some googling I came across some good tutorials in [Android Developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) and in [XDA](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/learn-to-create-your-own-themes/)

Comment: Thanks @Sid, I will head on over there and ask a new question.

Comment: I don't see a development question here. Just a user who wants to create a theme. I think this question is fine here.

Comment: I agree that this isn't necessarily a dev question, but if development can be involved (which shold mean greater options) then I'd prefer that. But if this question can remain here, I sure would love to see some answers. :)

Comment: @Sid This question definitely is not appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I was just saying. AFAIK when you are creating a phone theme, you have to do some coding, in which the folks from [so] are more interested. Just wanted to support the OP. You can start your work with the links I have added. At some point I have to agree with @Dan Hulme though. Good luck OP! (sorry. I can't type his name correctly). Let us know in [chat] when your theme is ready!! Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Themes on Android are internal to apps: they're not user-accessible things. Replacing the theme of every app on your phone entails building a new custom ROM with your changes, and may cause some apps to behave oddly or appear wrong, because they're relying on details of the Holo themes. These days, even phone manufacturers can't replace the themes of third-party apps, because the Android conformance tests verify that the Holo theme has not been modified. That's why, if you buy (say) a Samsung phone with a blue theme, only the built-in apps use that blue theme: third-party apps use the unmodified Holo theme.

Replacing the theme of an individual app is more feasible, but without the sources it requires decompiling and replacing the app's APK file, essentially making a new app. This kind of reverse-engineering may be illegal where you are, even if you don't intend to distribute your themed app; either way, your new app would not have access to the original app's data, and will fail any licensing or anti-piracy check the app performs.

Comment: This really pisses me off (customization becoming so limited these days). Btw, I'm not really trying to change the appearance of apps themselves, but mainly just the overall _system_ UI. (for example, background color of menus - I want it to be white, not black) :)